# Why does Trump want to increase military spending?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, military, budget, foreign-policy

From what I understand, [Trump is an isolationist](http://www.nationalreview.com/article/444321/trump-foreign-policy-isolationsim-america-first-allies-nato-trans-pacific-partnership) / non-interventionist, at least more so than previous presidents.

On the other hand, Trump wants to massively [increase](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-02-25/trump-vows-military-build-up/8303256) military spending:

> [Trump] wants "one of the greatest military build-ups" in American history.

It doesn't seem to make much sense to increase the already high US military spending while at the same time not wanting to engage in large-scale military actions. The current spending seems more than enough to finance small-scale actions against say ISIS.

> Why does Trump want **"one of the greatest military build-ups in American history"**? Is it part of future foreign policy? Just pandering to his base?

Comment: It's an excellent question but really no possible way to answer it beyond pure speculation.

Comment: You call it a "massive" increase. I seem to recall it was about $50 billion, which I think would be about a 10% increase in overall US military spending. Clearly this is more than an inflationary adjustment, but is it "massive"? But interestingly Trump is urging many other countries, mainly NATO allies, but also Japan and Korea to ramp up their defence commitments - even in the last cases to go nuclear.

Comment: How can anyone argue that $50 billion is not massive? It's still a 10% increase and if we were talking about any other program it would be an insane amount of money, especially for a President and a political party that constantly claims government is too big and spends too much money. Why do all these standards just disappear whenever it comes to military spending?

Comment: @WS2 if work gave me a 10% raise, I'd be massively happy.

Comment: Cynical view: The military represents a large chunk of the US economy; spending more on it is an ideological palatable way for a Republican president to (essentially) increase public spending. The military provides jobs, paid education too, and spends a lot of its money inside the US. And you can spend a lot on it without the usual inflation risks, as much is sunk costs, even in peace time. E.g. a multi-million dollar cruise missile doesn't offer any return on investment (in the usual sense). Once bought, it can't really be resold, and it's very much single-use.

Comment: I do not believe this is an idea that is unique to Trump. At some point the western countries will have to face up to a military China. What is happening in the South China Sea represents only the beginnings of a world hegemony. It seems inevitable to me that Western European countries will have to spend more too, especially Germany - currently ay 1.6% of GDP, compared to Britain at over 2.0%. But neither of these figures can continue, with America on 7.5%. To some extent Trump's Russia policy may be informed by similar considerations.

Comment: Generally republican voters are pro-military, so its a way of increasing his popularity in the run up to the election.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Bottom Line Upfront: If you don't allow the military to plan for maintenance, but keep them working, then it will cost more to fix them when you start giving them money.

Part of it is most certainly about pandering to his base. 67% of Republicans believe too little is spent on [defense](http://www.gallup.com/poll/204782/americans-say-spends-little-defense.aspx?g_source=defense&g_medium=search&g_campaign=tiles). Though, there is room for universal appeal, where this could be an effort to unify the country, because 41% of individuals [surveyed](http://www.gallup.com/poll/1597/confidence-institutions.aspx) have a great deal of confidence in the military, while an additional 32% have quite a lot.

The large portion for why Trump is pushing a budget increase is the decay of military readiness under sequester and continuing resolution. Lacking a formal budget and subsisting off of uncertain continuing resolutions for six years, usually followed by a 'government shutdown,' the military is challenged to put major maintenance items on contract. This causes maintenance to be deferred, for [ships](https://news.usni.org/2016/07/06/navy-fleets-unable-fix-500m-ship-maintenance-shortfall) and [airplanes](http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2016/04/17/budget-cuts-leaving-marine-corps-aircraft-grounded.html).

[Paul Ryan](https://youtu.be/Re-m7bmnSdE?t=6m14s) is on the note that Continuing Resolutions are uniquely bad for the Military.

In the long term, the military could likely stand to do with less money, assuming the operational requirements are firmly defined and curtailed. There is plenty of evidence of [wasteful spending](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2017/feb/14/bring-fiscal-responsibility-to-defense-spending/). A consist budget through the appropriations process would be preferable, so the military could at least plan on having money. Sustainment contracts are made years in advance, with negotiations for maintenance availabilities starting months prior. Since they military couldn't depend on money being there, they couldn't plan for maintenance. Add in the increased operational tempo, and you have equipment going without maintenance doing more work. Eventually things will break.

Comment: We differ politically but this is a great and concise answer.  +1

Comment: John McCain, who is no fan of Trump, has also been pushing for this for years. He wants an even higher budget.

Comment: @zabeus Sure, but McCain has a very [different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_positions_of_John_McCain#Foreign_policy) idea of foreign policy, which requires large military spendings.

Comment: Wouldn't implementing a formal budget and getting rid of government shutdowns and continuing resolutions be better solutions to the decay though? It seems that the problem isn't the size of the budget, but how the money is distributed. I'm probably missing something, but I'm not sure how increasing the budget helps here. Or is it a matter of catching up on what was lost during sequester etc?

Comment: @tim Yes. it is a matter of fixing the decay that happened in the last eight years that rendered the military incapable of fully carrying out its mission. The formal budget and other techniques would be better, but they would not help if not enough money is budgeted.

Comment: This is a good answer but I think that there could also be a economic benefit, from the president's perspective.  Combine this with an America-made clause and he gets a lot closer to meeting campaign promises about US manufacturing.

Comment: That's an... odd choice of answers for a poll. "A great deal" v. "Quite a lot"? I wouldn't know which one of those indicates the highest confidence level save for the order they're presented in.

Comment: @sabbahillel "it is a matter of fixing the decay that happened in the last eight years that rendered the military incapable of fully carrying out its mission." I really think that the idea that the military's ability to accomplish its missions has diminished deserves some mention in your answer directly.

Comment: @jpmc26 More than the links to delayed maintenance?

Comment: @DrunkCynic ..Somehow I confused myself about who wrote this answer. Sorry. But "delayed maintenance" naturally sounds less crucial than, "already having negative effects." If that is indeed the case.

Comment: @jpmc26 It is difficult to objectively say that the ability for the military to accomplish its current mission is diminished. We are only at the point where maintenance has been deferred, flight hours for training have been reduced, and underways for Naval ships have been closely controlled for fuel costs. The consequence of the Military being forced to choose operational tempo over maintenance has not yet been appreciably felt, but the bill can be seen on the horizon with a weather eye.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does Trump want to increase military spending?

President Trump wishes to increase spending to restore capabilities that have been declining throughout the past decade or so.

**Maintenance is reduced; forces are less ready**

The [Budget Control Act of 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budget_Control_Act_of_2011) (BCA) is one contributor to declining military capability. The Defense Department reduced operations and maintenance funds in response to the BCA. The cumulative effect from 2013 to 2016 of this reduction in maintenance has been significant. Example: at one point only 30% of Marine Corps. F/A-18 Hornet were mission ready, and 28% of Super Stallion helicopters were airworthy ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budget_Control_Act_of_2011#Defense_sequestration)).

**Aging equipment**

A budget increase is not only sought to restore deferred maintenance, it is also sought to recapitalize aging and outdated equipment. This [article](http://breakingdefense.com/2016/12/trouble-for-trump-fixing-sequester-dod-budget-may-be-a-bloodbath/) has subtle biases, but it does well describe how today's military capabilties are in large part a product on the 1980's defense build up. Reinvestment is needed. The article also describes the impact of less maintenance.

**Negotiator**

President Trump has a reputation as a negotiator from his real estate career. I opine that 50 billion is his entering argument as a negotiating tactic--that he realizes the final amount will be negotiated downward.

Even strong phrases such as *Greatest Military Build Up Ever* could be a negotiating tactic. It could very well be his entering statement. *Catching Up on Deferred Maintenance* would not do well with focus groups.

**Relation to isolationism and non-interventionalism**

> From what I understand, Trump is an isolationist / non-interventionist, at least more so than previous presidents.
>
> On the other hand, Trump wants to massively increase military spending

I suggest actually being the President can change one's opinions and attitudes. President Trump has probably evolved and has different thoughts and attitudes from Private Citizen Trump. It is to soon to tell where President Trump will act in regard to *isolationism* and *non-interventionalism.*

I offer the following thoughts:

- *isolationist* and *non-interventionalist* are difficult to uniformly define and apply. I imagine you could be a Defense Hawk and still wear one of those labels
- being an *isolationist* or *non-interventionalist* or does not
  necessarily mean less military capability (spending) is the norm
- President Trump's stance toward ISIS suggests he may be an *interventionalist*

Comment: While the BCA limited money available to the Military, it was the inability of the government to pass a budget, relying on Continuing resolutions instead, that had the greatest effect on maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

`increase military spending vs Trump is an isolationist`

Increasing military spending doesn't contradict necessarily  with Trump being an isolationist; He can reduce US aid spending to foreigners ([Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_foreign_aid) are some of aid receivers and some are hidden), and increase US military budget.

`not wanting to engage in large-scale military actions.`

How do you know this?
[*Time*](http://www.euronews.com/2016/12/07/time-calls-donald-trump-president-of-the-divided-states-of-america) calls Donald Trump "President of the Divided States of America". The situation is getting worse every day for Trump. A large-scale military action can lead to solidarity.

> If this is the scenario, we may see a severe killing of citizens,  e.g. US citizens or target country citizens (Accusing government about human rights,... ) ,... .

Although it seems a spending at first glance, but it can cause grate incomes.
Consider, for example, proxy wars in middle east, Consider [selling weapon to Saudi Arabia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12541/who-supplies-saudi-arabia-with-weapons) to kill people in Yemen,...

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_Elite can give you a good vision about the issue.