# Differences between Theresa May and Jeremy Corbyn's opinion on selling arms to Saudi Arabia?

Tags: united-kingdom, saudi-arabia, weapons, jeremy-corbyn, theresa-may

[UK is one of major suppliers of  Saudi Arabia with weapons](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12541/who-supplies-saudi-arabia-with-weapons), that has been accused of misusing them ([in Yemen](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2016/dec/18/uk-cluster-bombs-used-in-yemen-by-saudi-arabia-finds-research) or feeding terrorists).

Is there differences on *Theresa May* and *Jeremy Corbyn* 's opinion on selling arms to the Kingdom of Saudi Arabia?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jeremy Corbyn has repeatedly said he would **stop selling arms to [Saudi Arabia](https://www.forbes.com/sites/dominicdudley/2017/05/12/corbyn-vows-to-end-uk-arms-sales-to-saudi-arabia/)**. He said:

> Labour will re-examine the arms export licensing regulations to ensure that all British arms exports are consistent with our legal and moral obligations,This means refusing to grant export licences for arms when there is a clear risk that they will be used to commit serious violations of international humanitarian law. Weapons supplied to Saudi Arabia, when the evidence of grave breaches of humanitarian law in Yemen is overwhelming, must be halted immediately.”

---

Theresa May has repeatedly **defended arms sales** to Saudi Arabia.

During [Prime Minister Questions](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/arms-sales-saudi-arabia-theresa-may-staunch-defence-keep-people-streets-britain-safe-a7230836.html) she implied that (selling arms to Saudi):

> keeps people on the streets of Britain safe

Her home affairs spokesperson Amber Rudd (Former Home Secretary) said during a [BBC debate](https://www.rt.com/uk/390366-amber-rudd-saudi-arabia-arms/) that (selling arms to Saudi) was

> Good for British Industry

Theresa may has visited Saudi Arabia and further [defended arms sales](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-39485083) while she was their. Since Saudia Arabia has started bombing Yemen in March 2015, the UK has [licensed roughly £3.3 billion in arms](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/feb/12/british-arms-deals-with-saudi-arabia-high-court) to the regime. Theresa May was Home Secretary and later Prime Minister during this period.

---

*It is worth noting that in 2016 the US government under Barack Obama [halted all weapons sales to Saudi Arabia](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/12/13/us-halts-arms-transfer-saudi-arabia-civilian-casualties-yemen/) over widespread civilian deaths in Yemen*